# Exclude specific type in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I recently ran into an issue where I needed to exclude specific attributes of a data frame by their type. Here is a very simple example to replicate my problem with it.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  select_if(is.numeric)

iris %>%
  select_if(!is.factor)
```

While the first pipeline works, the second does not. While this is no issue if I had just two different types like in the example, I'm working with a data frame containing multiple (potentially unknown) types. In my case lists are to be excluded.

Including all other types might work for now but is tedious and I still don't know how to easily select multiple types without joining these types from multiple data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use `Negate`

```
iris %>%
   select_if(Negate(is.factor))
```

or with `~`

```
iris %>%
    select_if(~ !is.factor(.))
```